# TYPO3 - LUX Newsletter

Tags: typo3

I am trying to install the lux newletter extension on TYPO3 11 and have 2 questions:

I have entered the pid of the unscribscribed page on site configuration and also the full domain name is used in the configuration. I still get the error `No unsubscribe page identifier found in site configuration`,

Do you know why this error occur?

Another question: I have a TYPO3 page for the newsletter. This page is however not shown in the select field in the Newsletter view section? How can assign the page as a newsletter page?

Thank you very much for your support

I tried the configuration as described in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Where does the error occurs? In the site configuration module or in the LUXletter preview or while trying to send a mail
2. You may have to change the doktype of your page to newsletter. After that all those pages are available in the select box when creating a new newsletter

Comment: Thank you very much.

i changed the pagetyp of the page to newsletter and is now available in the select box.

In the LUxletter preview section i get the following error:
Class "TijsVerkoyen\CssToInlineStyles\CssToInlineStyles" not found

i have updated these: pagetyp 1562349004 is added in the configuration; Fluid Styled Mail Content is added in the root template. What could cause this issue?

Comment: The missing class error is new? LUXletter must be installed in composer mode, otherwise dependencies cannot be solved.